# How to process all Hbase data with Hive

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hdfs, hbase, batch-processing

I have a HBase with the 750GB data. All data in the HBase are time series sensor data. And, my row key design is like this;

deviceID,sensorID,timestamp

I want to prepare all data in the hbase for batch processing(for example, CSV format on the HDFS). But there is a lot of data in the hbase. Can I prepare data using hive without getting data partially? Because, if I will get data using sensor id(scan query with start-end row), I must specify start and end row for each time. I don't want do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Hive-Hbase integration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration#HBaseIntegration-Usage) and then `map hbase table` data to `hive table`.

Then by using **Hive-Hbase table** we can create full dump of Hbase table to Regular Hive table(orc,parquet..etc).

**`Step-1:Create HBase-Hive Integrated table:`**

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <db_name>.<hive_hbase_table_name> (key int, value string) 
      STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
      WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val")
      TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "<hbase_table_name>");
```

***`Step-2:Create Hive Dump of Hbase table:`***

```
hive> create table <db_name>.<table_name> stored as orc as 
         select * from <db_name>.<hive_hbase_table_name>;
```

**`Step-3: Exporting to CSV format:`**

```
hive> INSERT OVERWRITE  DIRECTORY <hdfs_directory> 
      ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
      select * from <db_name>.<hive_hbase_table_name>;
```

Refer to [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries) link for more details/options regards to exporting hive table.